# Can't post a channel in Slack: An API error occurred: not_in_channel

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, slack

Want to send Slack notification to a channel the user registers in Firebase Cloud Function. Actually, I want to send a notification when the field contents change in Firestore, but it occurs API Error.

> Error: An API error occurred: not_in_channel

It might be not Cloud Function error, should be Slack API error.

Oauth Scope:

[image]
The Code:

```
firestore
  .collection("users")
  .doc(id)
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    try {
        const token = snapshot.data().token;
        if (token) {
          const result = new WebClient(token).chat.postMessage({
            channel: snapshot.data().channel,
            text: "Posted!"
          });
          console.log(`Successfully send message ${result.ts}`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Not authenticated to slack ${error}`);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you add the entire code of your Cloud Function. What is exactly `firestore` in your code (`firestore.collection("users")...`)? Are you sure that `snapshot.data().channel`returns a correct value? Also note that depending on the kind of Cloud Function (background triggered or HTTPS) you may need to return the Promise returned by `postMessage()`.

Comment: Thanks I have it done!

Answer (score 4):

You have to `add App` in the channel.